# jQuery "*on click function*"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling with this code:

After choosing the html element and then applying the *on click function* what is the purpose of `tr`.

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
    alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: Have a look at delegated events in jQuery api http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: here you are delegating click event of TR to tBODY level

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `TR` is to specify what you will be clicking within the `#dataTable tbody` selector.  Try changing it to something else and see how it behaves differently.

Answer (score 0):

There's a subtle difference between:

```
$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", callback);  // 1
```

and

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", callback); // 2
```

The first selects every `tr` and calls `addEventListener` on each individually.

The second adds only one, special event listener to the `tbody` element. Whenever something inside is clicked, this listener checks if it is a `tr` and then delegates the event to your specified callback.

This gives 2 practical differences:

- One listener is added, instead of potentially very many (which can improve performance in some cases),
- if you add more `tr`s dynamically in the future, they will also react to `click` as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Events *bubble*. That's the primary thing you need to understand. If the user clicks on an `a` inside a `p` inside a `td` inside a `tr` inside a `table` (and so on), the click event will *bubble up* each of these elements and trigger all `click` event listeners in turn.

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function() {
```

This chooses the `#dataTable tbody` element to attach the event listener to, but it will filter and only react to events triggered by a nested `tr`. You could also do this instead:

```
$("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", function() {
```

But this would bind many individual event listeners to each and every `tr`. This may be a lot more inefficient or have other undesirable effects; for example if you keep adding or removing `tr` elements, you may end up with some `tr`s which have event listeners bound to them and others without.